# Dúvida - Utilizando map num array de arrays

Tags: javascript

preciso de ajuda. Eu queria saber como eu faço o mesmo procedimento, mas utilizando map?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Alguém poderia ajudar? Sei que nesse método, um dos valores que passamos para função de call-back é o índice, mas nesse caso eu teria dois valores referente ao índice, como manipular de forma correta?

Se alguém tiver a mesma dúvida, nesse caso eu resolvi meu problema usando o ForEach:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como não tinha problema mudar o array original, então tá aí minha solução para futuras consultas do pessoal.

Comment: Posta o texto do código contido na imagem.

Comment: Pessoal, depois de quebrar a cabeça aqui, eu consegui entender. Acabei usando forEach mesmo. Já que nessa situação não teria problema em mudar o array original, mas valeu por tentar ajudar. O jeito que eu fiz foi assim:                   
                                                                                                                           
 const arr = [[10,2,3,4], [5,6,7,8]];

arr.forEach((element, i) => {
    element.forEach((x, j) => arr[i][j] = x*2) 
});

Comment: Os 2 códigos **não** fazem a mesma coisa. Repare que o primeiro retorna um array com 8 números, e o segundo retorna um array com 2 arrays (e cada um desses arrays internos tem 4 números). Dito isso, `map` serve para mapear cada elemento do array para outro valor, ou seja, serve para quando a saída deve ter o mesmo número de elementos do original, o que não é o caso do primeiro código, que modifica a estrutura (parte de um array com 2 arrays de 4 números cada e retorna um array com 8 números). Apesar de até ser possível, `map` não é o mais adequado pra esse caso (pro segundo código, até vai)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Utilizando a função `map` ficaria assim:

```js
const arr = [[10,2,3,4],[5,6,7,8]];
let newArr = arr.map(function(subArr){
    return subArr.map(function(item){
        return item*2
   })
})
console.log(newArr)
```

Ou de maneira mais concisa:

```js
const arr = [[10,2,3,4],[5,6,7,8]];
let newArr = arr.map(subArr => subArr.map(item => item*2))
console.log(newArr)
```

Observe você chama a função `map` para cada array, inclusive os subarrays que são membros do principal. Cada execução irá retornar um array com o retorno da função anônima.

Comment: Muito obrigado, Marcos. Agora entendi. Vlw mesmo.

Comment: Disponha. Estamos aqui para ajudar. Lembre-se de aceitar as respostas que atendem sua necessidade. Abraço.